# How to configure MassTransit Saga in Asp.Net Core application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, masstransit, saga

I'm trying to integrate simple MassTransit Saga into ASP.NET Core application. 
During `ConfigureServices` I have:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<ISagaRepository<Request>, InMemorySagaRepository<Request>>();
    services.AddMassTransit(x =>
    {
        x.AddSagaStateMachine<RequestStateMachine, Request>();
        x.AddBus(provider => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingInMemory(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.UseInMemoryOutbox();
            cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(provider);
        }));
    });
}
```

Later I publish message:

```cs
var bus = context.RequestServices.GetService<IBusControl>();
await bus.Publish<IRequestCreated>(new
{
    CorrelationId = Guid.NewGuid(),
    ClientId = 1,
});
```

but it never reaches Saga instance.

My Saga looks like this:

```cs
    public class RequestStateMachine : MassTransitStateMachine<Request>
    {
        public RequestStateMachine()
        {
            InstanceState(x => x.CurrentState);

            Event(
                () => RequestCreated,
                x => x.CorrelateById(context => context.Message.CorrelationId).SelectId(context => Guid.NewGuid()));

            Initially(
                When(RequestCreated)
                    .Then(context =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Request received, id = {context.Instance.CorrelationId}");
                        context.Instance.RequestId = 10;
                    })
                    .TransitionTo(Active)
            );

            SetCompletedWhenFinalized();
        }

        public State Active { get; protected set; }

        public Event<IRequestCreated> RequestCreated { get; protected set; }
    }

    public class Request : SagaStateMachineInstance
    {
        public string CurrentState { get; set; }

        public Guid CorrelationId { get; set; }

        public long RequestId { get; set; }

        public Guid? ExpirationId { get; set; }
    }
```

I guess I'm doing something wrong but can't figure out what.

Comment: Are you calling Start on the bus? Typically by using the IHostedService which resolves the bus and starts it.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I was not calling `IBusControl.StartAsync`, that was the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to admit it is a bit confusing. We have `AddMassTransit` methods both in Microsoft DI package and ASP.NET Core integration package and they do different things.

`AddMassTransit` from the `AspNetCoreIntegration` package also registers the service that starts and stops the bus. So, this code would solve your issue:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<ISagaRepository<Request>, InMemorySagaRepository<Request>>();
    services.AddMassTransit(
        provider => 
            Bus.Factory.CreateUsingInMemory(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.UseInMemoryOutbox();
                cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(provider);
            },
        x => x.AddSagaStateMachine<RequestStateMachine, Request>()
    );
}
```

The method you use just registers the bus as `IBus`, `IBusControl`, `ISendEndpointProvider` and `IPublishEndpointPervider` in the container, but it doesn't take care about starting and stopping the bus. The method I used in the code sample also registers the host service and (optionally) adds health checks.